# Shopware data import

Tags: php, mysqli, zend-framework, e-commerce, shopware

I am using **shopware** as e-commerce engine, I creating articles from back-end for every articles, but it is a lazy process and is taking too much time. My question is, **Is there any way that I can import articles into shopware directly(to the database)**, because I have thousands number of articles. and It will take so much time if I Insert it from backend for each article.

Answer (score 1):

Shopware provides a free plugin [Shopware Import/Export](https://store.shopware.com/en/swagef36a3f0ee25f/shopware-import/export.html) for this. You can use it to import and export product and customer data, categories and product images using CSV and XML files. [Here](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-5-en/import-export/import-export-basic-module) you will find the documentation of the plugin.